# Is it possible to cbind multiple iterations of a nested for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, data-manipulation

I've got a nested for loop

and I'm trying to do it so that multiple iterations of the nested for loop

the end of the for loops looks like this:

| reps | MAD |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 23 |
| 10 | 21 |
| 20 | 19 |
| 30 | 17 |
| 40 | 15 |
| 50 | 12 |

And with every new iteration, I want it to add a column so that it looks like this:

| reps | MAD | MAD2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 23 | 25 |
| 10 | 21 | 22.5 |
| 20 | 19 | 20 |
| 30 | 17 | 19 |
| 40 | 15 | 17 |
| 50 | 12 | 15 |

```
out <- list()
output <- list()
i <- 1

for(patient in c("P01", "P02", "P03", "P04", "P05")){
  for(period in c("SBP", "Laser_Mean")){
    for(reps in c(5,10,20,30,40,50)){
        for(isim in 1:20){
          print(reps)
        
          db_temp <- db_s_abs_fix%>%
            filter(Patient==patient)%>%
            filter(Period==period)%>%
            group_by(Patient, Target_num, Period, Type)%>%
            sample_n(reps, replace=TRUE)
        
          last_delay <- matt_predict(db_temp)
          print(patient)
          print(period)
          print(reps)
          print(last_delay$delay)
        
          out[[i]] <- data.frame(patient=patient, period=period, reps=reps, delay=last_delay$delay, isim=isim)
          i <- i+1
      
      }

      
    }
  }
  out <- bind_rows(out)
  
    
  d_bp02 <- out%>%
    filter(period == "SBP")%>%
    dplyr::select(patient,
                  reps,
                  AV_BP = delay)
  
  d_laser02 <- out%>%
    filter(period == "Laser_Mean")%>%
    dplyr::select(patient,
                  reps,
                  AV_Laser = delay)
  
  d_final02 <- full_join(d_bp02, d_laser02)%>%
    group_by(reps)%>%
    mutate(av_diff = AV_Laser - AV_BP,
           abs_av_diff = abs(av_diff))
  
  d_final_mad <- d_final02%>%
    group_by(reps)%>%
    summarise(med_av_diff = median(av_diff),
              med_abs_av_diff = median(abs(av_diff)),
              MAD = median(abs(av_diff - med_av_diff)))
  
  d_final_mad <- d_final_mad%>%
    group_by(reps)%>%
    dplyr::select(reps,MAD)
  
  output[[i]] <- d_final_mad
  i <- i+1
  
}

  output <- do.call(cbind,output)
```

I have tried:

```
  output <- do.call(cbind,output)

stats <- foreach(i = 1:5, .combine=data.frame) %do% {
  output(i)
}

do.call(cbind, lapply(output, as.data.frame))
```

The above don't work

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  d_final_mad$i <- i  #to keep track of which iteration produced it
  output[[i]] <- d_final_mad # add it to your list
}
```

This one just gives me the same result 5 times

Comment: Hi, This is confusing to me.  Do you have a data frame you are starting with? Or a set of vectors?  Why are you using so many for loops to do this?

Comment: Can you please make a minimal example that shows the problem. We don't know what `db_s_abs_fix` is, we don't know what `matt_predict()` is.  There are a lot of print statements.  I can't figure out where `isim` comes from or why you are using `i`.    if the issue is that you are somehow getting a list of data frames and want to bind them then you can use `bind_rows()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of your question asks about binding an additional column of data to an existing dataset, so exactly how the new data is derived is irrelevant.  Like @Elin, I'm utterly confused by your workflow, so I'm going it ignore it and simply show you how to bind the new column.

First, using `cbind` as in your existing code.

```
d <- tibble(reps=c(5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50), MAD=c(23, 21, 19, 17, 15, 12))
# Define the data to be added in any way you like
newData <- c(25, 22.5, 20, 19, 17, 15)
# How many MAD* columns exist already?
madCount <- sum(str_count(names(d), "MAD\\d*"))
# Derive the new column names
colNames <- c(names(d), paste0("MAD", madCount + 1))
# Bind the new data
d <- d %>% cbind(newData)
names(d) <- colNames
d
  reps MAD MAD2
1    5  23 25.0
2   10  21 22.5
3   20  19 20.0
4   30  17 19.0
5   40  15 17.0
6   50  12 15.0
```

Do it again to test

```
madCount <- sum(str_count(names(d), "MAD\\d*"))
colNames <- c(names(d), paste0("MAD", madCount + 1))
d <- d %>% cbind(newData)
names(d) <- colNames
d
  reps MAD MAD2 MAD3
1    5  23 25.0 25.0
2   10  21 22.5 22.5
3   20  19 20.0 20.0
4   30  17 19.0 19.0
5   40  15 17.0 17.0
6   50  12 15.0 15.0
```

Now using tidyverse.

```
d <- tibble(reps=c(5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50), MAD=c(23, 21, 19, 17, 15,
# How many MAD* columns exist already?
madCount <- sum(str_count(names(d), "MAD\\d*"))
# Derive the new column names
colName <- paste0("MAD", madCount + 1)
# Bind the new data
d <- d %>% bind_cols({{colName}}:=newData)
d
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   reps   MAD  MAD2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5    23  25  
2    10    21  22.5
3    20    19  20  
4    30    17  19  
5    40    15  17  
6    50    12  15
```

Again, check that it works with more columns.

```
madCount <- sum(str_count(names(d), "MAD\\d*"))
colName <- paste0("MAD", madCount + 1)
d <- d %>% bind_cols({{colName}}:=newData)
d 
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   reps   MAD  MAD2  MAD3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5    23  25    25  
2    10    21  22.5  22.5
3    20    19  20    20  
4    30    17  19    19  
5    40    15  17    17  
6    50    12  15    15
```